# unable to move image to folder

Tags: php, sql

I am unable to move my image to C:\wamp64\www\mywork\images.

After I upload my image, there is a record in the database. However, when I check my C:\wamp64\www\mywork\images folder, the image is not moved. As one might suspect, it could be that my $target path is wrong. I have tried multiple times and still could not get it right.

Result from database : https://flic.kr/p/YZsQva 
Folder I am trying to put my images into: https://flic.kr/p/YGHRLQ

```
<?php
    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mywork");
    $msg = "";

    if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
        $target = "/mywork/images/".basename($_FILES['image']['name']);


        $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO movie (image) VALUES ('$image')";
        mysqli_query($db, $sql);

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
            $msg = "Image uploaded successfully";
        }else{
            $msg = "Failed to upload image";
        }
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM movie");

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Image Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<?php

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<div id='img_div'>";
            echo "<img src='/mywork/images".$row['image']."' >";
        echo "</div>";
    }
?>

    <form method="POST" action="manage.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="size" value="1000000">
        <div>
            <input type="file" name="image">
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit" name="upload">POST</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Echo the message variable after moving file

Comment: Apologies, I removed it during troubleshooting. The msg is Failed to upload image.

Comment: Thanks! I have tried the code below. The result is still the same. Give me some time while I add in more information about my program. Hopefully it will help.

Comment: What's the location of the file that you have sent. Because the path `$target` has a relative URL and would spend upon the location of the php file. So tell the exact location of this file, or the parent page, if this one is being included there.

Comment: Make sure destination folder have correct permissions.